# Android Firebase negative ServerValue.TIMESTAMP for ordering

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in Firebase for ordering in query. I set timestamp in my model class to dats for example 1494325636954.

[image]

```
public Attendance(String usico) {
    this.usico = usico;

    HashMap<String, Object> datsObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    datsObj.put("date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    this.dats = datsObj;

}
```

How can I set to datt negative ServerValue.TIMESTAMP for example -1494325636954 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Firebase Function to update the value to be negative, while maintaining the server accurate timestamp.

```
exports.makeNegativeTimestamp = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postID}/date').onWrite(event => {
    // get the timestamp from the DeltaSnapshot
    const timestamp = event.data.val();
    // ensure that the timestamp is a number
    if (isNaN(timestamp)) { return; }
    // only make negative if it's currently positive
    if (timestamp >= 0) {
        // returns a promise
        return event.data.adminRef.set(timestamp * -1);
    }
});
```

Comment: WARNING: writing to same location will trigger function twice. (First when positive value will be written. second when negative value will be written, however it wont write on second time but that's a waste of function trigger).
Better Choice: use a separate location for negative timestamp.

Comment: @RamizAnsari yes this may be a better technique (depending on the configuration you want) because it allows you to keep both the positive and negative timestamps to query.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeStamp in other cases but when it comes to firebase you don't need to go all the to convert timeStamp to negative for just sorting, my way is **put decrementing long or int whenever child is added (inside child's property) then use that as a sorting method**, this will simplify lot of time if you care only about order .